# Codeblocks occasionally freezes on start-up

Tags: code-blocks

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and the latest version of Codeblocks.

When I try to launch it either by opening a source code or launching the app directly, it freezes most of the time, and I get the "stopped responding" message and I have to force quit.

It doesn't always happen, I don't think there's a trigger.

I made sure I have the latest version by using

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:damien-moore/codeblocks-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install codeblocks
```